# C# Auto generation of class objects from XSD

Tags: .net, asp.net, xml

I'm creating an xml file and have an XSD file to work against.

I'm sure I remember reading somewhere that C# can automagically create class objects when given an XSD. So if I have an address element in XML I can have a generated C# class that uses the xsd to create the required properties of the class.

e.g.`<adress><postcode></postcode><phone></phone>`

would map to a class called Address with properties postcode and phone.

Is this sort of thing possible or did I dream it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.71).aspx) in the .net sdk.

use the /c switch to generate classes

Answer (score 0):

See link from @Jason w

I had to use this when working with OFX.  Be aware that if your xsd is complex, it will handle some cases in a funky way.

For instance some items get generated in a generic manner and will show up as

```
public class SomeTag
{

   public object Item[] { get; set; }
   public ItemCollection[] {get; set;}


}
public enum ItemCollection 
{
    SomeName,
    SomeOthername,
    AthirdYetExclusiveItem
}
```

Just be forewarned and well read...