# Converting XDR to XSD

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, schema

I have a an xml schema document in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms760255%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) format

```
<Schema xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-data" 
  xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
  <AttributeType name="scale" default="4.0"/>
  <ElementType name="GPA" content="textOnly" dt:type="float">
    <attribute type="scale"/>
  </ElementType>
  <AttributeType name="studentID"/>
  <ElementType name="student" content="eltOnly" model="open" order="many">
    <attribute type="studentID"/>
    <element type="GPA"/>
  </ElementType>
</Schema>
```

I wanted to generate classes in C# from given schema. I checked online that XSD.exe
can generate classes only from W3C XML Schemas. 
Is dere ne way to convert this format into W3C?

I am new to XSD and tried rewriting it but gettin loads of errors.
Please help.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You want to generate classes to use at runtime with reflection, or output `.CS` classes from a given scheme?

Comment: @LukeHennerley I am trying to generate .CS classes but XSD.exe says only W3C format can generate classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

[C# Auto generation of class objects from XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709697/c-sharp-auto-generation-of-class-objects-from-xsd)

Alternatively, I just wrote a generic modeler that's open source. You can use it to generate classes in whatever language you'd like.

https://github.com/homer6/modeler

If you fork the crudecppmodeler branch, it'd be similar to C#. Either that, or I can specifically design it for you.

It's not based off of XSD, but I could adapt it to. I plan to write support for multiplicity in the next few days.

Here's the sample format: https://github.com/homer6/modeler/blob/crudecppmodeler/simple.jm

Hope that helps...

Comment: @akanksha I've update this answer to include a canonical solution

Comment: Thanks for reply. I was actually looking for a way to convert XDR into XSD so that I can generate classes from the same. I dint find any way so I wrote my own XML parser.

Comment: Way to go. I love it when people fight against the "don't build it yourself" zombie chorus. You learn so much by writing things yourself even though there may be somewhat compatible alternatives. Kudos.

Comment: This is probably of no use to you, but I had started an XML parser in C. You might be able to use it as a starting point if you were interested in building a C option. Thought I'd mention it. https://github.com/homer6/xmldiff